# Login syntax for plink using ip, username, and password

Tags: ssh, cmd, putty, plink

I'm trying to connect to a VM through the command line using plink with this syntax:

```
plink -v "123.123.12.100 -l user -pw pass"
```

But I keep getting this

```
Looking up host "123.123.12.100-luser-pwpass"
Unable to open connection:
Host does not exist
```

When I just run plink with the ip address, I am able to login with my credentials.

I've looked around and the common solution is to check to see if PuTTY has default settings because then plink will use those, but there are no default settings, so it should use my arguments.

Should I be using a different syntax when using the ip address, username, and password arguments with plink in the command line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out the problem. If I remove the quotes from the command, it runs fine.