# how to write expect script to login and run command on remote box

Tags: linux, expect

i wanted to execute commands on remote linux box from windows and also wanted to collect result of executed command. Basically i have to pass 2 boxes to execute that command here is flow.
Login to a box
ssh to another box
run command
collect output of command locally (in file)

I tried following

```
F:\xyz>plink xyz@a1.b1.com -i F:\x\y\PRIVATEKEY.ppk -pw xyz 
 ssh -f root@166.1.8.1 yum upgrade Cyberc
```

but this is asking for password. I can do it by adding id_rsa.pub value in to authorized_keys but we dont have permission to do. So instead of that i wanted to write EXPECT script to pass user/pass and commands to complete my job.
Any help on EXPECT script would be much appreciated.

Comment: To script something like that you want [`expect`](http://wiki.tcl.tk/11583) not `awk`.

Comment: oho, yes, you are right

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11250564/how-to-automate-telnet-session-using-expect?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Unless the program on the remote linux host is interactive (i.e. it has prompts that the user must respond to), then you probably don't need to use `expect` - you can simply use `plink`  to connect to the remote Linux host from your windows machine and run the command.  You can specify the username and password to authenticate with the remote host in the `plink` command.   See the following links for more info:

```
http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.58/htmldoc/Chapter7.html
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12844944/login-syntax-for-plink-using-ip-username-and-password
```